# How to implement the singleton design pattern in JavaScript using classes?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I saw some examples how to implement the singleton design pattern using IIFE in javascript but I wonder how to implement it using classes?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Ex {
  static getInstance() {
    if (Ex.instance === null) {
      Ex.instance = new Ex();
    }
    return Ex.instance;
  }
}
Ex.instance = null;

const ex = Ex.getInstance();
console.log(ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do it, there is no need to use `class` for it. Most of the time you can just use a plain `Object` and treat it like a singleton:

```
export const MySingleton = {
  init(...args) { /*  */ },
  method(...args) { /* do whatever you want */ }
}
```

Then, for example:

```
import {MySingleton} from './path/to/mysingleton';

MySingleton.init(1, 2, 3);
MySingleton.method();
```

In case you want to have a *fluent* API, just return either `this` or the `MySingleton` object:

```
export const MySingleton = {
  init(...args) {
    /* do some stuff */
    return MySingleton;
  },
  ...
}
```

Results in:

```
import {MySingleton} from './path/to/mysingleton';

MySingleton.init(1, 2, 3).method();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no class in javascript :

> JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.

The point is that's impossible to define public or private methods in JavaScript while Singleton pattern is based on encapsulation with private constructor and public accessor.